# Google Password Reset OpenID Callback

Tags: authentication, callback, google-oauth, openid-connect, google-openid

I am busy with a Google Social login facility for our Company's infrastructure. I have just built an OAuth/OpenID connector, as detailed [in their documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect). That is working now, and through the JWT "id-token" have managed to connect the google user with our local user profiles, and issued a local session token for the user, which only expires when the expiry time is reached in a couple of days or he manually logs out.

Now, my question is, if this user goes and changes his password on his google account after he has authenticated with our system, for whatever reason he may have (lost phone, forgot password, account hack); Is there a way for Google servers to let my Client ID know through another callback that this particular user that authenticated through my app has reset his password, so that i can also invalidate all his sessions.

I saw that there are some Notification/Push Message services on some of the Google API's, but that is only when using those particular resources, which I am not. I'm just authenticating, and getting email address for username link, that's it.